# Link errors with C++ template class and nested classes defined in separate header files

Tags: c++, class, templates

For my homework assignment for my C++ class, I have to create a Linked List data structure. I have two classes at the moment. The List class (which is a template class) and the Link class. The Link class is nested within the List class, however, I am trying to define it in a separate header file. The issues I am having come from my lack of understanding in how the linking process works. Here is what I have.

**Contents of List.h**

```
#ifndef _LIST_H_
#define _LIST_H_

template <class T>
class List
{
protected:
  class Link;

public:
  List() : _head(nullptr) { }
  ~List() { }

  void PushFront(T object)
  {
    // !! Attention !!
    // When I uncomment this line I get the error:
    // error C2514: 'List<T>::Link' : class has no constructors...
    // My problem is the compiler doesn't know what Link is yet (I'm assuming).

    //_head = new Link(object, _head);
  }

protected:
  Link* _head;
};

#endif // _LIST_H_
```

**Contents of Link.h**

```
#ifndef _LINK_H_
#define _LINK_H_

#include "List.h"

template <class T>
class List<T>::Link
{
public:
  Link(T object, Link* next = nullptr)
    : _object(object), _next(next) { }
  ~Link() { }


private:
  T     _object;
  Link* _next;
};

#endif // _LINK_H_
```

**Contents of main.cpp (entry point)**

```
#include "List.h"

int main()
{
  int b = 5;
  List<int> a;
  a.PushFront(b); // If I comment this line, then the code compiles fine.
}
```

I'm sure this is a linking error that's occurring. Similar to this error on Microsoft's site that I looked up (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ce3zbbc.aspx), however, I'm not sure how to resolve it.

Comment: Why not include Link.h in main.cpp instead of List.h? What is the error message the compiler gives?

Comment: Since List depends on Link, you should include Link.h in List.h.

Comment: @ther. OK, when I included Link.h in main.cpp like you said, everything worked fine. However, since I'm trying to hide interface from implementation, the user shouldn't need to know about the Link class. So is there a way to not include it in main.cpp?

Comment: C2514 is a compiler error, not a linker error. Your problem is that List and Link are dependent upon one another, so you can't just have one of the headers #include the other.

Comment: If it was me, and I wanted the Link class to be a hidden implementation detail, I would nest the Link class within the List class.

Comment: @KristopherJohnson I did that, except I am trying to define it in a separate file. If you notice at the top of List class definition, I use a forward declaration class Link; Forgive me if I misunderstood you.

Comment: What I have done based on ther's comment is create a header file called ListLibrary.h and that file has the includes for List and Link header files. Then in main.cpp I simply include ListLibrary.h. Is that a logical approach?

Comment: `Link` is actually a template class though; it holds `T _object` which is why you can't hide it the way you're trying to. To get around this, you may be able to derive your template from a non-template abstract base class, and hold pointers to *that* class inside `Link` so it doesn't have to be `Link<T>`.

Comment: @tmpearce I'm confused about why Link is a template class? Because, as per ther's comment about including Link.h and List.h in main.cpp, everything compiles and works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With how the `#include`s are done, the compiler isn't looking at `Link.h` - so it can't find and generate the class it needs.

Comment: I see that being the case. The problem is unless I include Link.h in main.cpp (which I'm trying to avoid if possible) because my goal is to hide interface from implementation and Link is for internal use of the List class and the user doesn't need to know about it.

Comment: That is indeed the hard part with templated functions; what you hide from the user is also (usually, unless you get clever) hidden from the compiler since the class isn't generated unless it is needed.

Comment: It seems like the further I try to delve into C++ the more I realize I still have so much to learn about the basics. (= Anyway, when I remove all the templating and simply use a fundamental type (like int), it all works as expected. I'm going to research templates classes more I guess. Thanks for the replies.